# Pyinstaller with Pyside2 and Matplotlib is not working

Tags: matplotlib, pyinstaller, pyside2

I am not getting any executable to work by using Pyinstaller, Pyside2 and Matplotlib(PyQtGraph).

I tried different Python versions (3.5, 3.6, 3.7) latest release and development version of Pyinstaller, latest Pyside2 and latest Matplotlib versions. The latest "success" I've had is to create an exe file (dir or onefile doesn't change the result) for Matplotlib(3.0.2) or PyQtGraph(development 0.11) on python 3.5, pyside2 (5.12.0), but when I try to start the following error occurs:

ImportError: No module named 'numpy.core._dtype_ctypes'
[11856] Failed to execute script Pyside2PyQTGraph

When I only do a Pyside2 only example with a label only, everything works as expected. I also tried --hidden-imports numpy but it didn't help. I can share the source code of course. In addition I'd prefer to use Matplotlib but PyQtGraph is fine as well.

What else is left for me to try? What am I doing wrong? By the way I am using Windows 10.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication,QVBoxLayout
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas as Canvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import rcParams



class MatplotlibWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = Canvas(Figure())
        vertLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(vertLayout)
        self.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MatplotlibWidget()
    app.axes.plot(range(12), range(12))
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

Comment: If the PyQtGraphe minimal working example is required, I'll share of course. All scripts work well running python script.py.

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the current numpy release (1.16.0). Downgrading numpy via

`python -m pip install numpy==1.15.0`

solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped. Plenty of hours spend before that solution! Thank you!